# mysqldump without SQL_BIG_SELECTS

Tags: mysql

Trying to dump all databases for replication creation using

> mysqldump --all-databases --master-data --single-transaction >
>   all_databases.sql

Results in the following error

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM
>   `xxxtable`': The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows;
>   check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=#
>   if the SELECT is okay (1104)

Is there a way to ensure mysqldump works without having to restart the server and updating my.cnf in it? Definitely we wouldn't like to always enable big selects on the production server.

Using MySQL 5.6

Comment: How about issuing `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;` before dump and back to 0 after dump

Comment: And how would you do that considering mysqldump is launched from command line and sending the SET via a different mysql client wouldn't have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

Before launching the mysqldump you can send this query to check if big selects are available:

> SELECT @@global.SQL_BIG_SELECTS;

and then you can enable them using

> SET @@global.SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;

and disable again (after the dump) using

> SET @@global.SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 0;